# 32b multiplication in 8b uC with avr-g++ vs 32b multiplication on X86 with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, avr

### PROBLEM:

I'm doing a fixed point c++ class to perform some closed loop control system on an 8b microcontroller.
I wrote a C++ class to encapsulate the PID and tested the algorithm on an X86 desktop with a modern gcc compiler. All good.
When I compiled the same code on an 8b microcontroller with a modern avr-g++ compiler, I had weird artefacts. After some debugging, the problem was that the 16b*16b multiplication was truncated to 16b. Below some minimal code to show what I'm trying to do.

I used -O2 optimization on the desktop system and -OS optimization on the embedded system, with no other compiler flag.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TEST_16B    true
#define TEST_32B    true

int main( void )
{
    if (TEST_16B)
    {
        int16_t op1 = 9000;
        int16_t op2 = 9;
        int32_t res;
        //This operation gives the correct result on X86 gcc (81000)
        //This operation gives the wrong result on AVR avr-g++ (15464)
        res = (int32_t)0 +op1 *op2;
        printf("op1: %d | op2: %d | res: %d\n", op1, op2, res );
    }

    if (TEST_32B)
    {
        int16_t op1 = 9000;
        int16_t op2 = 9;
        int32_t res;
        //Promote first operand
        int32_t promoted_op1 = op1;
        //This operation gives the correct result on X86 gcc (81000)
        //This operation gives the correct result on AVR avr-g++ (81000)
        res = promoted_op1 *op2;
        printf("op1: %d | op2: %d | res: %d\n", promoted_op1, op2, res );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### SOLUTION:

Just promoting one operand to 32b with a local variable is enough to solve the problem.

My expectation was that C++ would garantuee that a math operation would be performed at the same width as the first operand, so in my mind `res = (int32_t)0 +...` should have told the compiler that whatever came after should be performed at int32_t resolution.
This is not what happened. The (int16_t)*(int16_t) operation got truncated to (int16_t).
gcc has an internal word width of at least 32b in an X86 machine, so that might be the reason I didn't see artefacts on my desktop.

### AVR Command Line

`E:\Programs\AVR\7.0\toolchain\avr8\avr8-gnu-toolchain\bin\avr-g++.exe$(QUOTE) -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -DNDEBUG  -I"E:\Programs\AVR\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\include"  -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -Wall -pedantic -mmcu=atmega4809 -B "E:\Programs\AVR\7.0\Packs\atmel\ATmega_DFP\1.3.300\gcc\dev\atmega4809" -c -std=c++11 -fno-threadsafe-statics -fkeep-inline-functions -v -MD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.o)"   -o "$@" "$<"`

### QUESTION:

Is this the actual expected behaviour of a compliant C++ compiler, meaning I did it wrong, or is this a quirk of the avr-g++ compiler?

### UPDATE:

Debugger output of various solutions
[image: Cast Comparison]

Comment: `res = (int32_t)0 +op1 *op2;` is `res = (int32_t)0 + (op1 * op2);`. the multiplication is evaluated before `+`. but `(int32_t) op1 * op2` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior of the compiler.

When you write `A + B * C`, that is equivalent to `A + (B * C)` because of operator precedence.  The `B * C` term is evaluated on its own, without regard to how it is going to be used later.  (Otherwise, it would be really hard to look at C/C++ code and understand what is actually going to happen.)

There are integer promotion rules in the C/C++ standards that sometimes help you out by promoting B and C to be of type `int` or maybe `unsigned int` before performing the multiplication.  That is why you get the expected result on x86 gcc, where an `int` has 32 bits.  However, since an `int` in avr-gcc only has 16 bits, the integer promotion is not good enough for you.  So you need to cast either `B` or `C` to an `int32_t` to ensure the result of the multiplication will be an `int32_t` as well.  For example, you can do:

```
A + (int32_t)B * C
```